# How to change where the default Ruby on Rails "redirect_to @user" path goes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, custom-routes

Currently I have a rails app where user profiles are viewed at "/users/:id", but I want to change that to "/:username". I've fixed the rails routes so that I have "match '/:username', :to => 'users#show', but I want to make it so I can easily use "redirect_to @user" within the controllers so that it goes to this new route. This still currently goes to "/users/:id".

How would I go about editing the default route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add to your match line the following: ":as => user_path" I think it would work, but I don't know if it would conflict with the already existing one... probably created by devise...

A bit more on this: As far as I know (I may be wrong here), `redirect_to @user`, just calls `user_path(@user)`. So if you create a new url helper called `user_path`, then it should work as you expect it to work.